# Trying to get property 'post_titile' of non-object

Tags: laravel

This is My Controller.

```
public function show(Posts $posts)
{
   $page = Posts::find($posts->id);
   //dd($page);
   return view('web_views.index',['page' => $page]);
}
```

This is my view page

```
<h4>{{$page->post_titile}}</h4>
```

Comment: how to call method `function show` ?

Comment: displaying my available pages in a table then click the each item it will goes to the show function<td><a href="/pages/{{$page->id}}">{{$page->pages}}</a></td>

Comment: Put dd($posts); check it and show us result

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use Route-Model Binding I think.

Your route (if you are using resource route, it's already done):

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', 'PostController@show); // domain.tld/posts/1
```

Your method should look like this:

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
   return view('web_views.index',compact('post'));
}
```

In your view:

```
<h4>{{ $post->post_titile }}</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be `$posts->id` you are passing, has no result in database so you need to check it by using `if-statement`

```
public function show(Posts $posts)
{
    $page = Posts::find($posts->id);
    if($page == null){
        $page = ['post_title' => 'Not Available'];
    }
    return view('web_views.index',['page' => $page]);
}
```

I believe this error is because of not finding data for an ID into database. So if as per above script will pass the fetched data to view otherwise it will push an item into `$page` array.

Comment: i have a data with id 1 so how could find may data with these id ? have to write anything in my model

Comment: @naseef for just testing you can pass it 1 into function  `Posts::find(1)`.

Comment: i use Posts::find(1) it  gives me Posts {#229 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "posts"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:16 [▶]
  #original: array:16 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]

Comment: how to get my show function with these id  here am calling my show function like this <td><a href="/pages/{{$page->id}}">{{$page->pages}}</a></td>